# Prove these subrings are ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R = R_1⊕R_2$ and let $I_1$ and $I_2$ be ideals of rings $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively. We consider $R_1$ and $R_2$ as subrings of R under canonical embeddings $R_i \rightarrow R$ and thus $I_1$ and $I_2$ are considered as subrings of R.

> (a) Prove that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are ideals of $R$.
>
> (b) If each $I_i$ is a maximal ideal of $R_i$, is the ideal $I_1 +I_2$ of $R$ maximal? Prime?

I honestly don't know how to approach either.  I think for a I want to show it just by using the definition, but that seems kind of tedious.  Is there a more efficient way?

For b, I know that an ideal I is maximal if and only if R/I is a field and an ideal P is prime if and only if R/P is an integral domain

Comment: Is the direct sum of fields a field?

Comment: @AlfredYerger yes.  how does that apply here?

Comment: $R = R_1 \times R_2 = \{ (a,b), a \in R_1, b \in R_2\}$ is a ring with pointwise addition and multiplication, and it has many zero divisors. The embedding is $\iota : a \in R_1 \mapsto (a,0) \in R_1 \times R_2$. Simply check $\iota(I_1)$ satisfies the axioms of an ideal.

Comment: @reuns Why can you use $\times$ instead of direct sum?

Comment: Because it is what $R_1 \oplus R_2$ means : $R_1 \times R_2$ with the pointwise addition and multiplication.

Comment: @JohnSmith "yes" is not the correct answer to "is the direct sum of fields  a field?"  Alfred's hint should be applied when judging whether $I$ is maximal by determining if $R/I$ is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $I_1\oplus 0$ is an ideal since if $x\oplus y$ is any element of $R$ and $a\oplus 0$ any element of the set, then 
$$(x\oplus y)(a\oplus 0)=xa\oplus 0\in I_1\oplus 0$$

However $I_1\oplus I_2$ need not be prime for example let $R_1=R_2=\mathbb{Z}$ and 
$$(2\oplus 1)(1\oplus 3)\in (2)\oplus (3)$$ but $2\oplus 1\not \in (2)\oplus 0$ and similarly.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you give some insight into how to do part a please?

Comment: I answered that.

Comment: Oh my bad,  Is that all that needs to be done?

Answer (score -1):

For part (b), the sum of two prime ideals is not necessarily prime. Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the ideals $\langle 2 \rangle, \langle 3 \rangle$.

As for maximality, is $I_1 + I_2$ an ideal? $I_1$ and $I_2$ are maximal, so what can you say about $I_1 + I_2$?

Comment: is $I_1 + I_2$ an ideal?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything remotely useful in either paragraph, not even hint-wise.

Comment: Sorry it seems as if I misread the problem.